# Boost condition_variable argument error

Tags: boost, condition-variable, recursive-mutex

I encounter an error in the code below.

```c++
recursive_mutex m_RecurMutex;
condition_variable cond;
unique_lock<recursive_mutex> lock(m_RecurMutex);
cond.wait(lock); // Error Here.
```

What is the reason causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the error is

```
mutex.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
mutex.cc:9: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::condition_variable::wait(boost::unique_lock<boost::recursive_mutex>&)’
/opt/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable.hpp:17: note: candidates are: void boost::condition_variable::wait(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&)
i
```

if not, please correct me. The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref.condition_variable) shows `boost::condition_variable::lock` takes a `boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>` as an argument, not a `boost::unique_lock<boost::recursive_mutex>` as in your example.

Comment: I thought the boost::recursive_mutex is a specialization of boost::mutex.

Comment: @peterwkc where in the documentation does it say that?

Comment: I just assume this is the case. Sorry.

Comment: @peterwkc, no reason to be sorry. We are here to help, good luck!

Answer (score 14):

You should use `condition_variable_any` instead, the semantics of this version is the same, but it allows all kinds of lock types. The regular `condition_variable` is however said to be potentially faster.